# Reference request : "instability" of analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVXKObDIhng) (starting at 1'30), Etienne Ghys is refering to the following result wrt to the instability of analytic continuation (on the disk unity):

**Notations:**

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the disk unity in $\mathbb{C}$ and $H(\mathbb{D}):=\{f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D} | f \mathrm{~holomorphic} \}$ the space of holomorphic function with norm $\le 1$.

For $r>0$, let $D_r$ the disk of center $0$ et radius $\tanh(r)$. For $f,g\in H(\mathbb{D})$, define $d_r(f,g)=\sup_{z\le \tan(r)} |f(z)-g(z)|$.

This defines a family of metric on $H(\mathbb{D})$ which is btw compact (Montel theorem).

For $\epsilon>0$, let $N(\epsilon,r)$ the minimal number of balls of radius $\epsilon$ for the $d_r$ metric we need to cover the whole space $H(\mathbb{D})$.

**Claim** : $N(\epsilon,r)$ grows very very fast, namely : $N(\epsilon,r) \sim C(\epsilon)\exp(\exp(r))$.

This gives a sense of how "instable" analytic continuation is : the fact that we can approximate an holomorphic function only up to $\epsilon$ on $\mathbb{D}_r$ isn't helpful at all to approximate its analytic continuation on a greater disk.

Ghys claims that this observation was (first ?) made by Kolmogorov.

**Question** :  what paper of kolmogorov (if any) is he referencing here ? where can i find a proper proof of this fact ?

Comment: Alas, the video is not accessible to us non-francophones.

Comment: He doesn't say much more than what i stated. For example, he gives no indication on how kolmogorov proved it, it's just a passing by remark.

Comment: Look for "A. N. Kolmogorov, *Asymptotic characteristics of some completely  bounded metric spaces*" and "A. N. Kolmogorov and V. M. Tihomirov, *$\epsilon$-entropy and $\epsilon$-capacity of sets in function spaces*"

Comment: Well, you can search for the topic in books in English. For example *Banach spaces of analytic functions*, by R. A. Hibschweiler, talks about it. Not sure if they prove that specific form. Using the keywords "$\epsilon$-entropy" and "$\epsilon$-capacity" many other sources should appear.